# is there a simple way to use features from tf.data.Dataset.from_generator with a custom model_fn(Estimator) in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using tensorflow dataset api for my training data, the input_fn and generator for tf.data.Dataset.from_generator api

```
def generator():
    ......
    yield { "x" : features }, label


def input_fn():
    ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(generator, ......)
    ......
    feature, label = ds.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
    return feature, label
```

then I created a custom model_fn for my Estimator with some code like :

```
def model_fn(features, labels, mode, params):
    print(features)
    ......
    layer = network.create_full_connect(input_tensor=features["x"], 
    (or layer = tf.layers.dense(features["x"], 200, ......)
    ......
```

when training :

```
estimator.train(input_fn=input_fn)
```

however, the code doesn't work since the features parameter for function model_fn is something :

> Tensor("IteratorGetNext:0", dtype=float32, device=/device:CPU:0)

code "features["x"]" will fail and tell me :

> ......"site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\array_ops.py", line 504, in _SliceHelper
>       end.append(s + 1)
>   TypeError: must be str, not int

if I changes input_fn to :

```
input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
  x={"x": np.array([[1,2,3,4,5,6]])},
  y=np.array([1]),
```

the code goes on because features now is a dict.

I have searched code for estimator and found it use some function such as

```
features, labels = self._get_features_and_labels_from_input_fn(
      input_fn, model_fn_lib.ModeKeys.TRAIN)
```

to retrieve features and label from input_fn, but I have no idea about why it passes me(model_fn) two different data type of features by using different dataset implements, if I want to use my generator mode, then how to use that type (IteratorGetNext) of features ?

thanks for any help!

**[UPDATED]**

I had made some change to code,

```
def generator():
    ......
    yield features, label

def input_fn():
    ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(generator, ......)
    ......
    feature, label = ds.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
    return {"x": feature}, label
```

however, still failed at tf.layers.dense, now it said

> "Input 0 of layer dense_1 is incompatible with the layer: its rank is undefined, but the layer requires a defined rank."

although the features is a dict :

> 'x': tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0' shape=unknown dtype=float64

in the correct case, it is something :

> 'x': tf.Tensor 'random_shuffle_queue_DequeueMany:1' shape=(128, 6) dtype=float64

I learned similar usage from

https://developers.googleblog.com/2017/09/introducing-tensorflow-datasets.html

```
def my_input_fn(file_path, perform_shuffle=False, repeat_count=1):
   def decode_csv(line):
      ......
      d = dict(zip(feature_names, features)), label
      return d

   dataset = (tf.data.TextLineDataset(file_path)
```

but there is no official example for the generator case which returns an iterator to a custom model_fn.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [examples on how to use `from_generator`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_generator), the generator returns the *values* to put in the dataset, not a dict of features. Instead, you build the dict in the `input_fn`.

Altering the code as follows should make it work:

```python
def generator():
    ......
    yield features, label

def input_fn():
    ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(generator, ......)
    ......
    feature, label = ds.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
    return {"x": feature}, label
```

### Replying to the update:

Your code fails because the tensor generated by the iterator of a `Dataset.from_generator` doesn't have a static `shape` defined (since the generator could, in principle, return data with different shapes).
Assuming your data has indeed always the same shape, <s>you can call `feature.set_shape(<the_shape_of_your_data>)` before `return`ing from `input_fn`</s> (See the edit blow for the proper way to do this).

### Edit:

As you pointed out in the comment, [`tf.data.Dataset.from_generator()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_generator) has a third parameter which sets the shape of the output tensor, so instead of `feature.set_shape()` just pass the shape as `output_shapes` in `from_generator()`.

Comment: thanks! however the code still failed on tf.layers.dense, i have made some description in question

Comment: great! it works now. according to your answer. I added the third parameter (i just used first and second parameter before sine third one is optional) to define the tensor's shape :     tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(functools.partial(geneator, dataset), (tf.float64, tf.float64), (tf.TensorShape([FEATURE_SIZE]), tf.TensorShape([]))), thanks again!

Comment: By the way, if I directly call set_shape on features["x"], it just returns a None value ????  so I have to define the type on from_generator function and the 
 then code works,  no idea about it, maybe Tensor Type "IteratorGetNext" can't be reshape directly.

Comment: It returns `None` because `set_shape` acts directly on the tensor it's called on, it doesn't return a new tensor (i.e., writing `my_tensor = my_tensor.set_shape([42])` is wrong, while just `my_tensor.set_shape([42])` does the job).

Comment: Also, thank you for letting me know about the third parameter of `from_generator`, I updated the answer to mention it as that's clearly the way to go in this case.

Comment: @GPhilo  Thanks for your answer. Can you help me out fix a similar issue here?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58442263/converting-a-numpy-function-into-tensor-flow